# Reinforcement learning wity incomplete information

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I want to program an AI using Reinforcement Learning. This game is Ghost! (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghosts_(board_game)) :

In Ghosts!, each player has four good ghosts and four evil ghosts – but only the player who owns a ghost can see whether it's good or evil (as with the pieces in Stratego). These ghosts start the game in the back rows of a 6x6 game board with the corners removed. Each turn, a player moves one of his ghosts one square orthogonally. Moving into an opponent's ghost kills that ghost. To win, you must get rid of your own evil ghosts, kill your opponent's good ghosts, or move one of your good ghosts off the board from one of your opponent's corner squares.

Which algorithm would you use to program an AI ?

Comment: This is very very broad. In what way are you thinking to combine RL and MinMax? And more important: do you think MinMax is a sound approach when there is hidden information?

Comment: I updated the post to give more precision. I don't know if MiniMax is a sound approach, probably not.

Comment: You only added the text from wikipedia, which was already available. If you just want some AI, go for MCTS. Otherwise you would have to grab some basics on RL and co. as there is no indication, that you already got some idea on how to proceed (and there are many ways). And yes, pure MinMax is wrong, and i also think Expectimax could be problematic.

Comment: One approach I'm trying is to change the game this way : instead of having red or blue phantoms, all your phantoms have no colors. Player 1 and Player 2 both have 4 red coins and 4 blue coins (like a currency). Now, if one phantom of Player 1 moves over a phantom of Player 2, Player 2 loses one random coin ... To win (with a blue in a special place or with having no reds), you can have similar reasonings.
That way, the game doesn't have hidden information anymore.

Comment: I don't know this game and thought about it just for 1 minute, but your changes sound like they will break the game / make it boring or dumb. In the original game i first thought the same, but then discovered the win-conditions. Without those exits (good g), the game would be dumb and there will be strategies with no-information-given random-moves so that the whole game is just a 50/50 luck-game. With those exits though, one has motivation to move an own good ghost to win, which gives away information. This part seems to lack in your modification and is the most important thing in my opinion.

Comment: I disagree. If you see your opponent moving its phantom to the exit, you don't know its color yet and when you take the risk of taking it, if your opponent has balanced its game well, its color is actually random (and with the corresponding odds of blues/reds ratio) over the possible configuration of red/blue phantoms. You can try to exit your phantom and you'll have to play the odds to "be blue" and leave.

Comment: It's more complex than that and you often need to risk it because one leaving ghost is game-over. I still stand by my importance-evaluation, but it's surely off-topic here.